# React javascript syntax error on question mark and dot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

while I am working on react, I got syntax error on this line:

`return str?.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + "..." : str;`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCGAx.png)

I strongly believe there is nothing wrong with the syntax. Please help me out with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need
`return str && str.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + "..." : str;`

Answer (score 0):

That's an improper way of using Conditional (ternary) operators. Based [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

A Condition is followed by a question mark (?).

Probably because it found a question mark (?) together with a string (which should have a space in between from `str?.length`) and the dot (.) should be next to a variable (that is valid for using `.length`.

You should write it this way.

```
return str.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + "..." : str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need, at least, version 14 of node in order to use this syntax.